# Metropolis Hastings sampler for several parameters

Tags: r, markov-chains, mcmc, hierarchical-bayesian

I have hierarchical Bayesian model with 32 unknown parameters (alpha_1, alpha_2,..., alpha_30, mu, .sigma^2).
conditional posterior distributions of  mu and sigma^2 are have closed forms, but conditional posterior distributions of ( alpha_1, alpha_2,..., alpha_30 ) are not closed forms, so I need to use Metropolis Hastings sampler within Gibbs sampler.
My question what is an algorithm and R code of Metropolis Hastings sampler of 30 parameters?

Comment: Depending on the application, the BUGS and JAGS Gibbs sampling engines make this fairly straightforward.  I typically use JAGS, and call it within R using the R2jags package.

Comment: Start reading up on JAGS or Stan (Stan doesn't use Gibbs, it uses Hamiltonian sampling, but is generally used for the same kinds of models). Your question asking for R code for one of these models is too broad for SO, look at the JAGS + Stan documentation.

Comment: I should  not use  BUGS or JAGS. I need to build  R codes .

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service, you will have to get started on your own and ask questions if you have specific problems. I don't know of any R libraries that allow you to build arbitrary Bayesian models in pure R, most Bayesian modelling I've seen is done in JAGS, Stan or INLA.